# Android NFC can't read Oberthur ID ONE (PIV type A large D)

Tags: android, nfc

I can read any card (or PIV card) using NFC and the IsoDep class - no problem.
But when I access a Oberthur ID One card it always immediately fails on the first line of code trying to read the card. The line is doing a transcieve call which always works with other cards.

The error reports as "Tag was lost". Has anyone experienced a similar problem?
Does anyone know why this card is different to loads of other cards?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TagLostException means that no answer was received. This could mean that the time-out value expired before the card sent a response. You could try increasing the time-out by calling [`setTimeout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#setTimeout%28int%29) before calling `transceive()`.

Comment: Thank you, yes this works for Gingerbread!

On Ice Cream Sandwich the NFC failure sound alerts and doesn't even launch my app. Is there a way to permanently increase the timeout on ICS?

Comment: Apart from a custom ROM image, there is no way to permanently increase the timeout for a particular NFC technology on ICS.

Comment: Dear NFC guy, the ROM image might be a temp solution now - I have the Java source but can't find the value of the default NFC timeout eg for IsoDep tag, do you know where or how I would set that? Thanks

Comment: I would try to experiment with `NXP_ISO_XCHG_TIMEOUT` in `external/libnfc-nxp/inc/phNfcConfig.h`.